# WPF Standalone Application showing different views

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am building a WPF Standalone application. It consists of a menu on the left of the window and when a menu option is selected I want a page showing content related to the option selected shown on the right hand side of the window.

If a user selects a different menu option then the new view will be loaded.

If the user selects a previously selected menu option then that view will be shown but it will have held it's state. So if has a result set for customers with "bob" as a first name then when I view it again the result set will still be showing.

My questions is what is the best way to implement this.

Pages are not suitable as the app will not be viewed in a browser.

I could not see a Master Page -> content layout approach.

So is it a case of loading custom controls?

I am using the MVVM pattern.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement something similar detailed here using "workspaces". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use TabControl with TabStripPlacement value set to "Left" - is that what you are looking for?